# Awk, print result

Tags: awk

Why does

`awk '{print 3 + 3}'`

not work, but:

`echo 3|awk '{print $1 + 3}'`

does?

Couldn't the first statement just output 6? What is the easiest way of printing the result of a calculation?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{print (2+2)}'` <- This?

Answer (score 6):

AWK statements consist of a *pattern* and an *action*: quoting the [GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Patterns-and-Actions)

> a rule is executed when its pattern matches the current input record

In the first case, you are not providing any input record - so you get no action. In this case, you could use the special pattern `BEGIN`

```
awk 'BEGIN {print 3 + 3}'
```

Comment: You could also just hit "Enter" again after typing in `awk '{print 3 + 3}'`.

Answer (score -1):

Equally well you could do

```
awk 'END {print 3 + 3}'
```

Comment: This is not "equally" good as [steeldriver's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268430/80216).  When the only action statements in an `awk` script are associated with the `BEGIN` pseudo-pattern, the script runs immediately, without looking at its input.  With your answer, `awk` reads (and ignores/discards) its input until it reaches EOF, and only then executes the statement.

Answer (score -2):

With bash `echo $(( 3 + 3))` or with  `bc`

Comment: Asked specifically for `awk`.

Comment: I asked specifically for awk.

Comment: so?  it doesn't always matter what you specifically ask for.  When you are asking a wrong question (such as using the wrong or even sub-optimal tool for a job), a good answer will inform you of that fact.  "Q. how do i shoot myself in the foot with a banana?"  A. "You don't, you use a gun.  Better yet,  it's a good idea to avoid shooting yourself in the foot, you should do X instead."....and a lot of wrong questions *are* the OP metaphorically shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: Unless the OP is actually trying to learn something about Awk...

Comment: @cas: Unless I am actually trying to learn something about Awk... But, yes, you are right that sometimes it is OK to question the OP's assumptions and intentions. In this case, however, awk is a perfectly capable tool.

Comment: even if the OP is trying to learn something about `awk`, it's still not wrong to post an answer about alternatives.  Certainly not wrong enough to downvote.  And don't forget, the final question was `What is the easiest way of printing the result of a calculation?`, some answers may focus on the `awk` context of the rest of the question, others may focus on the `easiest way`.